# How to override [Authorize] attribute in the MVC Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC Web Api Controller that uses the [Authorize] attribute at the class level.  This makes all of the api methods require authorization but I'd like to create an attribute called [ApiPublic] that overrides the [Authorize] attribute.  There is a similar technique described [here](http://farm-fresh-code.blogspot.com/2011/04/default-authorization-filter-provider.html) for normal MVC controllers.

I tried creating an AuthorizeAttribute based of the System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute but none of the overridden events are called if I put it on a api method that has the [Authorize] at the class level.  Anyone have an idea how to override the authorize for the web api?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ApiPublicAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can I recommend that you just use [AllowAnonymous] instead?

You can attribute this on any method and it will override the Authorize attribute you've specified at the class level, saving you from writing your own attribute.